# How to use escalation boundary event attached on the boundary of a Sub Process of Camunda

Tags: camunda

I have attached an intermediate escalation boundary event on the boundary of a Sub Process of Camunda. But it does not fire.

I know it is not firing because I have not triggered the event. My question is how to do that. I have gone through a lot of Camunda docs(docs on this is sparse) but was not able to find any details about firing escalation events. Neither I have found any example about the same.

I don't have much clue as to how I can do this. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Model a throwing escalation event in your process model. When the process engine executes the throwing event, a catching event subprocess on the same level of subprocess or an event (boundary event or subprocess) on a higher BPMN scope are  triggered.
You cannot trigger escalation from the outside via code.

There are plenty of examples and explanations here: https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.4/reference/bpmn20/events/escalation-events/

Example diagram:
[image]

When the process engine reaches the `Escalate` event, it throws the escalation event for you and catches it as well at the boundary event. If it does not reach the event, it won't throw it.

Comment: Thanks. I am afraid this still leaves the question answered. How to throw or trigger an escalation event. That is precisely I had asked.  I have already read before details from the link you gave but there is no explanation on this very point. Also there are no examples avaialble on this.

Comment: I added a diagram. I don't know how to make it any clearer than that, sorry.

Comment: Many thanks for the detailed process diagram. In fact I just managed to do the same you had described. I just gave a thought and based on instinct I thought making the flow reach a escalation point will work and it worked. The only difference between my diagram and yours is I do not have to end the flow after the flow reaches a escalation point. It just works fine. But I am not sure if this is according to best practice. But I sincerely thankful to you for taking your time to provide the above diagram.